# JPQL 'Function' doesn't send operator

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am using `EclipseLink` over `Spring Boot` and have this jpql in a repository:

```
    @Query("select function('pMonth',p.payDay) ,sum(p.price) " +
            "from FullPayment p where " +
            "group by function('pMonth', p.payDay)"
    )
    List<Object[]> paymentMonthlyHistory();
```

but it does not send the operator `p.payDay` calling my custom function `pMonth`. Here is the database error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION adventure_db.pMonth; expected 1, got 0
Error Code: 1318
Call: SELECT pMonth(), SUM(PRICE) FROM panel_fullPayment WHERE ((PAYDATE >= ?) AND (TRANSACTIONAMOUNT >= PRICE)) GROUP BY pMonth()
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

I use `Mysql` as DBMS. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo. The field name is `payDate` but I wrote `p.payDay`. I put the answer here to emphasize that if you mistype the field name here, it won't show you an error on boot, but will generate a wrong query.